# Rhino Mocks 3.5 Test that property setter was not called

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to test that a property setter has not been called using Rhino Mocks 3.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is entirely possible:

```
public class OneProperty
{
    virtual public int MyInt
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[Test]
public void IntWasSet()
{
    var prop = Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateMock<OneProperty>();

    prop.MyInt = 5;

    prop.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.MyInt = Arg<int>.Is.Anything);

    prop.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Running this test on Rhino Mocks 3.5 results in the following error:

> Errors and Failures: 1) Test Error :
>   InterfacerTests.TestMatchesInterface.IntWasSet
>   Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException
>   : Expected that
>   OneProperty.set_MyInt(anything); would
>   not be called, but it was found on the
>   actual calls made on the mocked
>   object.

I discovered the `Arg<T>` syntax [from this part of the Rhino documentation](http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#Properties).

Answer (score 2):

Set the property to some known value in the test. Call the code that *won't* change the property, then assert that the property is the same as it was. Shouldn't need to use Rhino Mocks for that.

Comment: The advantage of using Rhino Mocks here is that you can be sure that the value was not set.  Without it, all you can guarantee is that the final value of the property is as expected.  In some cases, like where the setter has another side effect, this might be important.